# Iterate over collections union

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 instances of `IEnumerable<string>` and need to iterate over both of them. Is it possible to iterate within single `foreach`?

Comment: @Cory: It might compile, but unless he wants to iterate over the **distinct** elements in the enumerables, it will not work the way he thinks it will.

Comment: OMG there is a `Union` method! I'm blind stupid.. Now will check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Enumerable.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I think it will do what you want:

```
foreach (string str in Enumerable.Concat(collection1, collection2))
{
}
```

Or

```
foreach (string str in collection1.Concat(collection2))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Union` will not work unless you want to iterate over the set union of the two `IEnumerable`. The set union is defined as the unification of both, without duplicates. So if you rely on iterating over duplicates, it will not work, you'll have to use `Concat` for that.

Comment: Nope; you have it backwards. From the MSDN docs: 

The Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>) method differs from the Union method because the Concat<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>) method returns all the original elements in the input sequences. The Union method returns only unique elements.

Comment: That's what I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: It is. I just read it backwards =)